# XSL to find common nodes xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to find the common nodes in 2 XMLs. I have written an XSL after looking some examples online to get the intersection of 2, but is giving error while merging when used with Java.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="V9_XML_PATH" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="schedule">
<xsl:variable name="match" select="/schedule/scheduleItem[measurements/measurement=document($V9_XML_PATH)/schedule/scheduleItem/measurements/measurement]"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$match">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$match"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My 2 XMLs are:

**XML1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schedule>
  <scheduleItem scheduleId="1" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
    <measurements>
      <measurement>ADM010000</measurement>
    </measurements>
    <measPeriods>
      <period day="10" duration="10" hour="10" interval="45" minutes="0"/>
    </measPeriods>
  </scheduleItem>
  <scheduleItem scheduleId="2" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
    <measurements>
      <measurement>ADM020000</measurement>
    </measurements>
    <measPeriods>
      <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="15" minutes="0"/>
    </measPeriods>
  </scheduleItem>
</schedule>
```

**XML2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schedule>
  <scheduleItem scheduleId="1" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
    <measurements>
      <measurement>ADM010000</measurement>
    </measurements>
    <measPeriods>
      <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="15" minutes="0"/>
    </measPeriods>
  </scheduleItem>
  <scheduleItem scheduleId="2" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
    <measurements>
      <measurement>ADM030000</measurement>
    </measurements>
    <measPeriods>
      <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="15" minutes="0"/>
    </measPeriods>
  </scheduleItem>
</schedule>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schedule>
  <scheduleItem scheduleId="1" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
    <measurements>
      <measurement>ADM010000</measurement>
    </measurements>
    <measPeriods>
      <period day="10" duration="10" hour="10" interval="45" minutes="0"/>
    </measPeriods>
  </scheduleItem>
</schedule>
```

Here V9_XML_PATH="XML2" which is passed as parameter to XSL, and if any tag matched in XML1 and XML2, the record from XML1 I have to take. Please notice `period` tag in expected output. 
I don't know what's the problem, it's not working in Java. Please help me to find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know what's the problem

There are several problems with your second template:

First, you're matching on `schedule` when you should be matching on `scheduleItem`.

Next, the way you define the `match` variable makes no sense: you want to know if the other document contains a `scheduleItem` whose `measurement` value is equal to the `measurement` value of the current `scheduleItem`.

Finally, there's no `measSchedule` node in your XML2 document.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:template match="scheduleItem">
    <xsl:variable name="match" select="document($V9_XML_PATH)/schedule/scheduleItem[measurements/measurement=current()/measurements/measurement]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$match">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry, its schedule only in XSLT, by mistake I put here measSchedule while uploading. And apart from this, I used
`/schedule/scheduleItem[measurements/measurement=document($V9_XML_PATH)/measSchedule/scheduleItem/measurements/measurement]`
because the line
`<period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="15" minutes="0"/>`
should come from XML1, and XML2 I am giving parameter to my XSLT.

Using the opposite way is working fine which you told `document($V9_XML_PATH)/schedule/scheduleItem[measurements/measurement=current()/measurements/measurement]"`

Comment: @pankaj_ar I am not sure what you're saying. Is your question answered or not?

Comment: I have modified the samples and expected output. Notice tag `period` that whose attributes should come from XML1.

Comment: Would it not be sufficient to change `<xsl:copy-of select="$match"/>` to `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>`?

Comment: Sorry didn't worked. Or dont know if I am doing wrong. Can you please update in your answer

Comment: @pankaj_ar See the edit to my post. -- P.S. "*didn't worked*" is not a good description - you should describe your actual result.

Comment: This worked in unix when used with xsltproc but when used in Java, I am getting result as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<measSchedule name="NE3S">




































</measSchedule>`

Comment: @pankaj_ar Such result is not possible with the input you have posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80803/discussion-between-pankaj-ar-and-michael-hor257k).

Comment: Let us not. If you are using a different input, then either edit your question or post a new one.

Comment: The XML I have posted here is in modified form as I cant post actual one. So, the tags also I renamed. Actual output came as: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> <schedule"> </schedule>`

Comment: @michael...the problem I found is with copy-of tag. Anything which I am writhing inside copy-of tag is not being copied. That's why I got above XML after applying XSL. I tried with other XSL also to run and found this issue.

Comment: See the link: http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-bugs/044nwc838c/28097-new-xsl-copy-of-not-working-properly  I am also facing the same problem. Is there any alternative of copy-of

Comment: @pankaj_ar Since you have the identity transform template in place, you should be able to use `<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>` instead of `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>`.